# VBA compares each row in column 1 to in column 2. Displays a msgbox if rows don't match

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to compare cells from 2 columns (columns 1 and 3) and have a msgbox pop up if a1 is not equal to c1, a2 is not equal to c2..and so on. Column A has fixed data. Column C pulls data from column B as it is entered.

Below is my code. This code only works if I physically enter data to column C but does not work if column data is pulled from column B.

How can I make this work when data is entered in column B instead of in Column C?

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Target Is Nothing Then Exit Sub
    If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    If Target.Column <> 3 Then Exit Sub
    If Cells(Target.Row, 3).Value <> Cells(Target.Row, 1).Value Then

        MsgBox "not match"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: If there's a formula in C, then you have to use the `Worksheet_Calculate` event. The Change event doesn't fire when cell formulas are recalculated.

Comment: If the physical change is made in column B change to `If Target.Column <> 2 Then Exit Sub`

Comment: Why use VBA? Why not use a formula that puts "not match" in a helper column?

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> If Target.Column <> 3 Then Exit Sub
> ```

This is the instruction bailing the procedure out if the modified cell isn't in column 3 (C).

> *How can I make this work when data is entered in column B instead of in Column C?*

Change the `3` for a `2` [as Scott mentioned](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59293502/vba-compares-each-row-in-column-1-to-in-column-2-displays-a-msgbox-if-rows-don#comment104791824_59293502).

```
If Target.Column <> 2 Then Exit Sub
```

And now the procedure will bail out if the modified cell isn't in column 2 (B).

Comment: Thanks guys...changed target.column <2> then exit sub did it.  Thanks again for your help.